# What is the origin of Jefferson Davis' nickname "Banny"?

Tags: confederacy

I have seen a few letters between Davis and his wife, Varina in which she refers to him as "Banny." This name seems to have nothing to do with his birthplace or, for example, his middle name. (It almost seems like a nickname she might have, but it is his.)

I have read quite a bit about him and other Confederates but none of them use this name that I recall -- I am pretty sure it is between the couple only/

Comment: [The Life of Varina Howell Davis: First Lady of the Confederacy – Brewminate: A Bold Blend of News and Ideas](https://brewminate.com/the-life-of-varina-howell-davis-first-lady-of-the-confederacy/) *But what never amazed her was the love, devotion and dedication that continued to flow between her and her husband. Like most lovers, **the two had pet names for each other: she called him ‘Banny’ and he called her ‘Winnie.’***

Comment: @MarkJohnson: Thanks. I am guessing we will never know where his nickname came from. Perhaps some popular story he liked (or a song) -- no relationship to anything about his real name, etc. "Winne" strikes me as a variation on "Varina".